# react js local_image load in github page

Tags: reactjs

These are my files structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Malmb.png

In the src/app.js, I write:

```
 <img src={'/photo/IMG_0509.jpg'} />
```

I know that it will take the image from public folder. It's fine when I run it in local host. But when I push it to github and gh-pages using:

"predeploy": "npm run build"

"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"

The page loaded successfully but the image had wrong path. How can I fix this ? I have googled and somepage said I need add a process.env.PUBLIC_URL, but I cannot find what is "process.env.PUBLIC_URL" and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

process.env.PUBLIC_URL is just a short-hand for that publicly accessible application directory. The process.env stuff in general is injected by [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) as a helpful way to get to information you might need in your application.

In your case, you'd probably use it like this.

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/photo/IMG_0509.jpg"} />
```

Check out this [article](https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7) that breaks it down a bit more in a nice, concise way.

Comment: Why I don't need to add it in local host and it still works fine ?